# I want to use metal to convert RGB to YUV

Tags: metal

I want to use metal to convert RGB to YUV, and the YUV data I get now shows that there is a problem, can anyone help me?

```
kernel void rgb2yuv(
                    texture2d<float, access::sample> inTexture [[ texture(0) ]],
                    device float *outBufferY [[ buffer(0) ]],
                    device float2 *outBufferUV [[ buffer(1) ]],
//                    device float *outBufferV [[ buffer(2) ]],
                    constant uint2 &outSize [[ buffer(3) ]],
                    constant TestColorConversion &colorConversion [[ buffer(4) ]],
                    uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]
                    ) {
    if (gid.x >= outSize.x || gid.y >= outSize.y) {
        return;
    }
    
    float3 rgb = inTexture.read(gid).rgb;

    float3 ycbcr = colorConversion.offset + colorConversion.matrix*rgb;
    
    uint idx = gid.y * outSize.x + gid.x;

    outBufferY[idx] = ycbcr.r;
    outBufferUV[idx] = ycbcr.gb;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem in the YUV data? It is not clear in your question. If you edit it to make this clear, you'll have a much better chance of getting useful answers.

Comment: In general, check the powerful Xcode Shader Debugging tools, they'll help you to identify errors in your code: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/shader_authoring/developing_and_debugging_metal_shaders?language=objc